# apply css rules on programmatically created div

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I have a site that creates new divs in real time (using JS).
The class of each div is "conv". 
My problem is, that the css rules that I have written for this class doesn't apply to the new divs.
`conv.length` is the length of the xml file I am using.

The JS:

```
for(i=0; i<conv.length;i++){
  var div= document.createElement("div");
  div.id="conv"+i;
  div.class= "conv";
  div.innerHTML=conv[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  div.style.height="50px";
  div.style.overflow="hidden";
  document.getElementById("conv").appendChild(div);
}
```

The CSS:

```
.conv {
  background-color:#CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `class` property of an HTML element is a special case, it is not the `class` attribute. That one is accessible via `className`:

```
div.className="conv";
```

Comment: Well, I know it because I stumbled on the same issue a few years ago :-)